# Checking permissions in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, permissions, swift2, touch-up-inside

No matter where I add code to check permissions for things like camera/mic/photos, the popup confirmation always kills my app or sends me back a few view controllers.

**An example is as follows.**

I have few view controllers in (part way through a registration process) when I have a page that deals with the permissions. Users tap a button to deal with the camera permission which uses the following code.

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) !=  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted :Bool) -> Void in
            if granted == true {
                // do something
            } else {
               // determine whether not determined, denied etc and do something else
            }
        });
    }
```

However as soon as the iOS confirmation pops up, it throws the app back 2 view controllers. In other cases (e.g. on a `viewDidLoad`) permission requests kill the app as soon as the choice is made.

Any ideas what am I missing in my setup or how to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: how about denied ?

Comment: @Misha - I understand there are more options for the user to choose and these are dealt with if needed but irrelevant to the question I think

Comment: but how will the app decide what to do in case permisiion is denied ?on another note have you added keys in plist?

Comment: @misha - it will decide what to do based on what the code says to do - in this case it doesn't really do anything but the point is that the view rolls back when the popup shows - the rest is irrelevant but I'll edit the question to avoid future confusion

Comment: Irrespective of what it does if not authorised, the point is that I always authorise but the process crashes or rolls back the views, either as soon as it asks for the decision or when authorised

Comment: @misha as for the plist keys - can you give me more information? I have added the key/values for the text that shows on the popup e.g., Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood my comment, what I did meant was

```
if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) !=  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized { // here you are checking if it's not authorized i..e  it's denied, NotDetermined or Restricted
   ....
    }
 else if if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) ==  AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized
// do the something in case it's autorized
```

I'm listing keys here -

```
     <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
     <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
     <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
     <string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Comment: Thanks Misha - I have the status check for determining what the state is currently and the other code (granted==true) for determining their choice on the popup - as for the keys I'm adding these as I have one for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription but the camera/photos ones are in with a key 'Privacy - Camera Usage Description' (not sure where I got that key from) - will check back shortly with results

Comment: it seems that I had a missing entry in info.plist for one of the descriptions which was causing it to pop to the closest navigationController (which is weird but no matter) - adding all descriptions I can think of seems to have sorted the problem